# Calling default done function in jquery file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using the  [Jquery file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tree/75d11179fd9c248c061c8eb428782bb556c8db0a) for uploading the file.

```
    jQuery('#UploadForm-form').fileupload({
'maxFileSize':20000000,
'acceptFileTypes':/(\.|\/)(csv)$/i,
'done':function(e,data)
       {
        // do something here
       // call defaultDone here        
       },
'url':'/manage/upload?parent_id=1',
'autoUpload':false,
'maxNumberOfFiles':1});
```

The problem is that in the done function above, I want to do something and then call the [default done function](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/75d11179fd9c248c061c8eb428782bb556c8db0a/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js#L139) provided by the plugin.

How can I do that ?

Comment: What is the exact requirement to do it?

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com The EXACT requirement is that I have to set the file name in a hidden field and then show the downloadTemplate as it shows by default. I guess you are the one who has downvoted. May I know why ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to memoize your default function. Hopefully you will get some idea from following code.

```
// Initialize your file upload object
jQuery('#UploadForm-form').fileupload({
    'maxFileSize' : 20000000,
    'acceptFileTypes' : /(\.|\/)(csv)$/i,
    // Don't override default done function here
    // You have to memoize default function from widget instance later.
    // Hence, I comment following line
    // 'done':function(e,data)
    // {
    // // do something here
    // // call defaultDone here
    // },
    'url' : '/manage/upload?parent_id=1',
    'autoUpload' : false,
    'maxNumberOfFiles' : 1
});
// Memoize and call the default done as follows.
var widgetInstance = $('#UploadForm-form').data('blueimp-fileupload') || $('#UploadForm-form').data('fileupload');
widgetInstance.options.defDoneFn = widgetInstance.options.done
widgetInstance.options.done = function myCustomFn() {
    // do something here
    widgetInstance.options.defDoneFn .apply(this, arguments);
};
```

**Note:** I have tested the code against http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html. There could be some changes like data key`(.data(<data key>)` if you are using different version of fileupload.